# Как передать URL страницы с параметрами action=?

Tags: php

```
<?php
/**
 * [PHPFOX_HEADER]
 */

defined('PHPFOX') or exit('NO DICE!');

class Phpfox_Gateway_Api_belentlik implements Phpfox_Gateway_Interface
{
    /**
     * Holds an ARRAY of settings to pass to the form
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $_aParam = array();

    /**
     * Holds an ARRAY of supported currencies for this payment gateway
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private $_aCurrency = array('USD');

    /**
     * Class constructor
     *
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }   

    /**
     * Set the settings to be used with this class and prepare them so they are in an array
     *
     * @param array $aSetting ARRAY of settings to prepare
     */
    public function set($aSetting)
    {
        $this->_aParam = $aSetting;

        if (Phpfox::getLib('parse.format')->isSerialized($aSetting['setting']))
        {
            $this->_aParam['setting'] = unserialize($aSetting['setting']);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Each gateway has a unique list of params that must be passed with the HTML form when posting it
     * to their site. This method creates that set of custom fields.
     *
     * @return array ARRAY of all the custom params
     */
    public function getEditForm()
    {       
        return array(
            'apiKey' => array(
                'phrase' => Phpfox::getPhrase('apiKey'),
                'phrase_info' => Phpfox::getPhrase('apiKey_info'),
                'value' => (isset($this->_aParam['setting']['apiKey']) ? $this->_aParam['setting']['apiKey'] : '')
            ),
            'merchantAccountCode' => array(
                'phrase' => Phpfox::getPhrase('merchantAccountCode'),
                'phrase_info' => Phpfox::getPhrase('merchantAccountCode_info'),
                'value' => (isset($this->_aParam['setting']['merchantAccountCode']) ? $this->_aParam['setting']['merchantAccountCode'] : '')
            )
        );
    }

    /**
     * Returns the actual HTML <form> used to post information to the 3rd party gateway when purchasing
     * an item using this specific payment gateway
     *
     * @return bool FALSE if we can't use this payment gateway to purchase this item or ARRAY if we have successfully created a form
     */

    public function getForm()
    {       
        $bCurrencySupported = true;

        if (!in_array($this->_aParam['currency_code'], $this->_aCurrency))
        {
            if (!empty($this->_aParam['alternative_cost']))
            {
                $aCosts = unserialize($this->_aParam['alternative_cost']);
                foreach ($aCosts as $aCost)
                {
                    $sCode = key($aCost);
                    $iPrice = $aCost[key($aCost)];

                    if (in_array($sCode, $this->_aCurrency))
                    {
                        $this->_aParam['amount'] = $iPrice;
                        $this->_aParam['currency_code'] = $sCode;
                        $bCurrencySupported = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if ($bCurrencySupported === true)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }   
        if( isset ($_GET['action'])) {
```

header( "Location: ". $url ); 
$url = 'https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action='.$arr['action‌​'];
}

```
    $aParts = explode('|', $this->_aParam['item_number']);
    $aForm = array(
        'url' => 'https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/signature?', 
        'param' => array(
            'requestType' => 'Sale',
            'merchantAccountCode' => $this->_aParam['setting']['merchantAccountCode'],
            'transactionIndustryType' => 'EC',
            'accountType' => 'R',
            'accountNumber' => '4111111111111111',
            'accountAccessory' => '0422',
            'CVV2' => '123',
            'amount' => '10',
                            'currency' => $this->_aParam['currency_code'],
            'lang' => 'RU',
            'item Code' => '999999',
            'transactionCode' => '0000000001',
            'customerAccountCode' => '1818',
            'ticketNumber' => $this->_aParam['item_number'],
            'memo' => 'xyz',
            'itemCount' => '2',
            'items' => '',
            'holderType' => 'P',
            'holderName' => 'MARS+SNIKERS',
            'holderBirthdate' => '',
            'countryCode' => 'US',  
                            'state'=>'',
                            'street'=>'',
                        'city'=>'',
                        'zipCode'=>'',
                        'phone'=>'',
                        'email'=>'',
                        'apiKey' => $this->_aParam['setting']['apiKey'],
    ),


    );
```

$response = file_get_contents('https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/signature');
parse_str($response, $arr);

```
    if ($this->_aParam['is_test'])
    {
        $aForm['param']['demo'] = 'Y';

    }

    return $aForm;
}

/**
 * Performs the callback routine when the 3rd party payment gateway sends back a request to the server,
 * which we must then back and verify that it is a valid request. This then connects to a specific module
 * based on the information passed when posting the form to the server.
 *
 */
public function callback()
```

Comment: При первом запросе мы получаем responseType=signature&responseMessage=Approved&responseCode=A01&action=0HQcy........... Теперь нам нужно передать всё это на https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action=

Comment: Кто нибудь знает как передать полученные данные в header('Location: .......... ?

Comment: Конкатенация (соединение) строк: `header('Location: '.$url);`

Comment: Я пробовал разделить на | и прописать типа$a form = array (url => $url . '',
'http' => array(
'header' => "Location: $url",
'method' => 'POST',

Comment: Уточните вопрос, пожалуйста. Что необходимо передать и куда?

Comment: При каждом обращение https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/signature? мы получаем ответ responseType=signature&responseMessage=Approved&responseCode=A01&action=9dbE1блаблабла  теперь нам нужно перейти на https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action=<from 1st response> и вставить полученные данные action=

Comment: @Андрей При каждом обращение lk.belentlik.tm/gates/signature? мы получаем ответ responseType=signature&responseMessage=Approved&responseCode‌​=A01&action=9dbE1бла‌​блабла теперь нам нужно перейти на lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action=<from 1st response> и вставить полученные данные action=

Comment: [`parse_str();`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: @Андрей вы могли бы помочь дописать? за $

Comment: Кто нибудь знает как дописать class?

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
$response = file_get_contents('https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/signature');
parse_str($response, $arr);
header('Location: https://:lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action='.$arr['action']);
```

Comment: Вставил после ` 'apiKey' => $this->_aParam['setting']['apiKey']

   )
  ); 

  if ($this->_aParam['is_test'])
  {
   $aForm['param']['demo'] = 'Y';
  }
  return $aForm;

$response = file_get_contents('https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/signature');
parse_str($response, $arr);
header('Location: https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action='.$arr['action']);  
 }` но не работает

Comment: Суть не в том, чтобы скопировать и вставить, а в том, чтобы разобраться и применить.

Comment: `код'apiKey' => $this->_aParam['setting']['apiKey']

   )
  ); 

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => 'Location: https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action=',
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query('param'),
         ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents('https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/signature', false, $context); тоже не выходит`

Comment: А если вот так прописать `if (!isset($_GET['action'])) {
 header('Location: https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action='.$arr['action']);
 die();
 }` а дальше $response = file_get_contents('https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/signature');
parse_str($response, $arr);

Comment: header('Location: надо как то по другому прописать, он блокирует  getForm()

Comment: Каким образом блокирует?

Comment: Когда я уже перехожу на сайт для оплаты и вызываю форму выбора платежных систем, то форма виснет и не открывает все способы оплаты.

Comment: не знаю, будет ли правильно прописать как нибудь так `$header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= 'Location: https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action=' `

Comment: я думаю стоит начать как то так ` if( isset ($_GET['action'])) { 
 header( "Location: ". $url ); 
} ` единственное как теперь прописать $url на реальный url

Comment: `$url = 'https://lk.belentlik.tm/gates/paypage?action='.$arr['action'];`

Comment: вроде всё то, да не то...

Comment: Блин, что то вобще не получается, а как всё хорошо началось

Comment: Напишите актуальную версию кода на [Pastebin](https://pastebin.com) и отправьте ссылку на него сюда, опишите проблему. Попробуем разобраться.

Comment: [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/zrZ26Ph1)

Comment: Очень странно, строки 114-115 - получается, сначала даётся команда перейти на `$url`, и только затем объявляется `$url`? И потом, не `header( "Location: url=".$url );`, а `header('Location: '.$url);`

Comment: Просто посмотрите текст ответа (который выше). Все команды исполняются последовательно, не переставляйте их. Если Вы даёте команду перейти на страницу, то переменная с адресом этой страницы должна быть объявлена раньше, но никак не после команды.

Comment: Ну вот переделал , но .... [ссылка](https://pastebin.com/1jYYC7vt)

Comment: Что не так? Вроде всё корректно.